# jquery event in Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension, adding a "tab" to a website:

```
(function () {  
   $(".tabs").append('<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#MyNewTab" onclick="MyExtClick()">NEW TAB</a></li>');
}());
```

Until this point, everything is perfect, but when I tried to add an "onclick" event to the tab, ie: a simple alert with a message, but it didn't work

```
function MyExtClick(){
   alert("This is an alert");
}());
```

Is that a syntax problem?

Comment: Instead of using on inline onclick, try defining the click handler in your javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
have you tried this?

```
$("a").click(function(e){
   alert("This is an alert");
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

**or**

```
$("a").live("click", function(e){
   alert("This is an alert");
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

If this doesn't work, can you post it on jsfiddle or jsbin so that I can test it?

Comment: Hi Jude, yeap and it didn't worked, now the tab is not even loaded to the site